# find() returning maximum value of unsigned int

Tags: c++

I'm finishing up a homework assignment that requires me to redirect input and output in the same command.  When searching the command (that is a string) for both "<" and ">" the if statement always returns true.  This is because it finds the maximum value of an unsigned int on a 64bit system.

The `if (uCommand.find("<",0) && uCommand.find(">", 0))` statement will always be true.  When I run the uCommand.find(">", 0) in gdb is returns 18446744073709551615.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
// local variables
char **toks;
int retval;
int ii;
int redirect;
int search;
string fileName;

// initialize local variables
toks = NULL;
retval = 0;
ii = 0;

// main (infinite) loop
while (true)
{
    // get arguments
    toks = gettoks();

    if (toks[0] != NULL)
    {
        for (ii = 0; toks[ii] != NULL; ii++) {
            uCommand += " ";
            uCommand += (string)toks[ii];
        }
        // Search for input, output, or dual redirection
        if (uCommand.find("<", 0) && uCommand.find(">", 0))
        {
            redirect = dualRedirect(toks, uCommand);
            addHist(uCommand);
        }
        else if (uCommand.find("<", 0)) {
            redirect = inRedirect(toks, uCommand);
            addHist(uCommand);
        }
        else if (uCommand.find(">", 0)) {
            redirect = outRedirect(toks, uCommand);
            addHist(uCommand);
        }

        // Look for hist or r and execute the relevant functions
        if (!strcmp(toks[0], "r"))
            repeatCommand(uCommand);
        else if (!strcmp(toks[0], "hist")) {
            addHist(uCommand);
            showHist();
        }
        else if (redirect == 0) {
            execCommand(toks);
            addHist(uCommand);
        }

        // Increment the command count.  This only runs if a something is entered
        // on the command line.  Blank lines do not increment this value.
        commandCount++;
    }
}

// return to calling environment
return(retval);
```

}

Comment: The maximum unsigned int is -1 if interpretted as a signed int.  Are you sure it doesn't return a signed int?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `uCommand` is a `std::string`, as you didn't include its declaration.

`std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` when the find fails to find anything. This is normally `(size_t)-1`, `size_t` is an unsigned type, meaning that `npos` is an extremely large value. You can't treat this as a `bool` as anything non-zero is treated as `true`.

Your code should be

```
if (uCommand.find("<", 0) != std::string::npos && uCommand.find(">", 0)  != std::string::npos)
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Any idea why gdb shows that it is the above number rather than -1?

Comment: I updated my answer slightly to use `size_t`. As it is unsigned, a value of -1 when cast `size_t` gives a huge value.